# Using reflexivity in Coq

Tags: coq

I was trying out the examples from the Coq documentation Software Foundations (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Induction.html#lab40) when I noticed that to solve the example give in the link:

```
Theorem andb_true_elim1 : ∀b c : bool,
  andb b c = true → b = true.
Proof.
  intros b c H.
  destruct b.
  Case "b = true". (* <----- here *)
    reflexivity.
  Case "b = false". (* <---- and here *)
    rewrite ← H.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

we are destructing b which appears on the left of c for "andb". However to do the exercise that follows in the book i.e.

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : ∀b c : bool,
  andb b c = true → c = true.
Proof.
  (* FILL IN HERE *) Admitted.
```

I found the same method does not help. "reflexivity" did not help which I assume is due to the position of 'b' in the subgoal. Eventually I completed the proof in the following manner:

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c:bool,
andb b c = true -> c = true.
Proof.
intros b c H.
destruct c.
Case "c=true".
reflexivity.
Case "c=false".
rewrite <- H.
destruct b.
reflexivity.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Can someone explain why the above code worked and the following dint?

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c:bool,
andb b c = true -> c = true.
Proof.
intros b c H.
destruct c.
Case "c=true".
reflexivity.
Case "c=false".
rewrite <- H.
reflexivity.
```

Comment: questions about why a piece of code is working or not ( and debugging) are off topic here.

Comment: In the last proof, you `destruct c` instead of `b` as in the very first proof.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the last proof doesn't work is the way `andb` defined and the way Coq simplifies such definitions (`reflexivity` performs some simplifications *in the goal*).

Here is the definition of `andb` in Coq.

```
Definition andb (b1 b2:bool) : bool := if b1 then b2 else false.
```

Notice that we make decision basing on the *first* parameter. So, when you use `destruct` on the *first* argument and then use `reflexivity`, you allow Coq to reduce `andb b c` (to `false` or to `c`).

Because of the unsymmetrical definition of `andb`, case analysis on the *second* argument doesn't work, since Coq can't reduce the `if` expression in the function's body.