# Simplify assumption

Tags: coq

I want to proof the following term:

```
Goal forall x y, andb x y = true -> x = true.
```

which is equivalent to

```
Goal forall x y, ((andb x y) = true) -> (x = true).
```

Thus my approach on paper would be to go over all options of x and y and show that whenever the left-hand side is true (true = true) the right-hand side is as well (true = true), which would satisfy the requirements for an implication.

```
Proof.
  intros x y A. destruct x.
  - destruct y.
    + reflexivity.
    + reflexivity. (*I am not certain why this works but I assume due to the implication*)
  - destruct y.
   (* here I am lost*)
Qed.
```

I'd need to simplify the assumption as there is currently `A:(false && true)%bool = true` and a evaluation of the `&&` and would yield `false`, thus, `A:false = true` and I could rewrite the goal to show `false = false` which would be solvable with `reflexivity`. But using `simpl A.` yields `Error: Cannot coerce A to an evaluable reference.` and a direct `rewrite A` yields `Error: Found no subterm matching "(false && true)%bool" in the current goal.`

How can I simplify my assumption A from `(false && true)%bool = true` to `false = true` to rewrite my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your direct question:

> How can I simplify my assumption A from `(false && true)%bool = true` to `false = true` to rewrite my goal?

**(1)** Just use `simpl in A.` (There is the keyword **"in"** after `simpl`).

**(2)** Another variant would be

```
rewrite <- A. (* notice the arrow which shows rewriting direction *)
reflexivity.  (* this will also perform simplification *)
```

---

**(3)** Considering the first comment in the source code in the OP:

> reflexivity. (* I am not certain why this works but I assume due to the implication *)

That line works because `true = true` (look at the goal), just like in the first subgoal. You actually don't need dustructuring on the second argument (`x = true` in that case and (informally) you already have proved your goal), but since you do `destruct y.` you need to prove `true = true` twice, hence the need for using `reflexivity` twice.

**(4)** I also ought to notice that you don't have to consider 4 possible variants for arguments, since `andb` is defined in [short-circuit style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214005/using-reflexivity-in-coq) for some more details. So, using the tactics have been used in the question, I'd write the proof as follows:

```
intros x y A.
destruct x.
  - reflexivity.                         (* x = true *)
  - simpl in A. rewrite A. reflexivity.  (* x = false *)
```

Comment: Once you move towards larger Coq developments you may temped to use a move concise style. This would be my proof `now destruct 0, 0.`

Comment: @ejgallego It's very nice, thanks! However, I was trying to use the tactics that are familiar to the OP :)

Comment: @Sim See the above comment by ejgallego. Another variant would be `destruct x; auto.` (but `auto` is more complex, than `easy`, upon which `now` is based)

Comment: I like to showcase a more compact stuff for beginners, even if it is not very good for teaching. A common complain they make is about trivial proofs being very verbose or complex in Coq, and indeed, most teaching material doesn't precisely encourage an "effective" proof style.

Comment: @ejgallego Agreed. I guess A. Chlipala's CPDT is a notable exception, but I'm not sure if it's beginner-friendly. Do you happen to know any tutorials demonstrating an 'efficient proof style'? [even at some advanced level]. Google doesn't help :)

Comment: @ejgallego By the way, `now destruct 0, 0.` generates and solves 4 subgoals, whereas `now destruct x.` does that using 2 subgoals.

Comment: I'd say i prefer the two-destruct version as it matches OP's intuition on the "paper" proof. Regarding a more effective proof style, I'd dare to say that it is an unsolved question for the moment. 

I most enjoyed peeking into the math-comp libraries, a bit of a steep "tutorial", but it was fun. But math-comp is far from providing an effective proof style for a lot of domains.